# HTC Evo 4g LTE AVD Setup

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am brand new to Android development. 
I just bought a HTC Evo 4g LTE, my first smart phone and I want to write an app.
I am following the instructions at https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/HOWTO_Setup_Android_Development
I am running Fedora 17 on an x86_64 system.

I am at the point of setting up the AVD for my phone. I ran tools/android in order to set it up.

My phone is running Android version 4.1.1
Options for target are:
4.1.2, Google APIs Level 16, 4.2, and Google APIs Level 17  -- Should I select 4.1.1?

Wikipedia says I have a Snapdragon processor
Options for processor are: 
ARM, MIPS, and Intel atom  -- Which should I select?

Do you have any other hints to help me properly set up my AVD?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to test on your phone, you don't need to setup an AVD.  I would recommend setting one up with the same specs as yours though, just because it's faster to debug on an emulator than a physical phone.

One downside to testing/debugging on an emulator is that you only get vanilla Android.  You can't test compatibility with the manufacturer's programming (like TouchWiz, HTC Sense, Sprint Connections Optimizer, the datepicker on some HTCs and Motorolas that only goes down to 1970, etc).